# Is it possible to refer to a user-defined conversion template in a using declaration?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, using-declaration, conversion-operator

In a class `B` inheriting from class `A`, it's possible to use a `using` declaration to bring members of `A` into `B`, even templates, like this:

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    void foo();
};

struct B : private A {
    using A::foo;
};
```

But can it be done for conversion templates?

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    operator T();
};

struct B : private A {
    using A::operator /* ??? */;
};
```

There seems to be no way of referring to the template by name, but I would love to be proven wrong or get some clarification.

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: @RSahu Presumably to inherit a converting constructor without requiring public inheritance.

Comment: @Ayjay, if that's the case, then use of `private` inheritance is ill-conceived, IMO.

Comment: @RSahu Ayjay is correct. To be more specific, I want to allow some class `C` to inherit from `B`, but `C` should not have access to `A`'s protected methods. However, I want `A`'s public methods to remain public, including this conversion operator. I know I could work around this in a few ways, but I would rather avoid writing extra code for such little benefit.

Comment: @Apples, that seems like design flaw.  I don't know how much control you have over these classes.  If you have control of what goes in `A`, you could separate `A` into two classes -- one that `B` can inherit `public`ly and the other `private`ly.

Comment: @RSahu I'm aware of all that - and if you'd like to post that as an answer, go ahead - but if you're trying to say that this is an XY problem, it is not. Consider this a question of syntax, not design. I added the `language-lawyer` tag to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can cast to the base class and convert it explicitly:

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    operator T() {
        return T{};
    }
};

struct B : private A {
    template <class T>
    operator T() {
        return static_cast<T>(static_cast<A&>(*this));
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    int i_a = a;
    int i_b = b;
}
```